# Validating and cleaning text data

Tags: validation, text, nlp, data-cleaning, bigdata

I'm wondering how one would go about validating that text data you pull and clean, considering that you can't either validate the number values or read every single entry.

My specific case is dealing with email text data, pulled from a .mbox file. So there are all different types of formats - ie signatures, etc - and the text I want to analyze is essentially a subsection of the body.  Let's say I figure out a method to extract what I'd like, then how do I go about validating that the data I will be working with is what I specifically want?

Answer (score 0):

Build a test framework that can extract data from a sample message and compare the result to a desired result.

Add a randomly selected message along with the desired output to the test framework.  Refine your extraction/cleaning code as needed until this test passes.

Then add another randomly selected message and continue to refine the extraction code until all the tests pass.

Repeat until the messages in the test framework represent a large enough subset of your dataset that you can have high confidence you've handled all the possible cases.

If you ever discover a message that doesn't do the right thing, you can add it to your test suite and modify your code with confidence that it doesn't break any of the known cases.